# Calculated Field based on an Relation Aggregate with Filter Conditions in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two tables, `users` and `purchases`. They are inner-joined in the Data Source on a `user_id`.

For simplicity's sake let's assume that `users` only has the `user_id` field. `purchases` is made up of `user_id`, `amount` and `category`.

Now, I want to create a calculated field for the `users` table that will resolve to a boolean indicating whether a `user` had spent at least 200 on purchases with a `category` of "chair".

In a Pseudo-code/Tableau-langue hybrid, this is what I am looking to achieve:

```
IF TOTAL(SUM([amount] WHERE category="chair")) >= 200 
THEN TRUE 
ELSE FALSE 
END
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705801/calculate-price-difference-for-each-row-in-tableau/52723749#52723749 See if this gets you what you need? I know how to do what you want, but I sort of answered it for another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data pane sidebar, right click on the user field and create a set based on the User field, defined by the condition

```
sum(if category=‘chair’ then [amount] end) > = 200
```

You can use the set as a filter, as a list of users, or as a Boolean function in a calculation